# C# MVC5 - Inserir Campos com 4 Dígitos Decimais

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estou fazendo uma inserção no banco de dados (SQL Server 2008) de um campo configurado para 'decimal(10,4)', do qual eu tento inserir/editar, pela minha aplicação C# MVC5, um campo da minha model do tipo 'decimal'.

O fato é que quando eu debugo o código, até antes do momento do 'context.SaveChanges()', ele está com as casas decimais corretas, ex.: 0,8999. Porém, quando eu faço o SaveChanges ele acaba gravando no banco de dados da seguinte forma '0,8900'.

Estou usando o EF 6.1.3 com a engenharia reversa para gerar as models (DbFirst). Quando eu insiro o comando abaixo na minha classe de contexto que é gerada automaticamente, funciona normalmente, porém tenho que alterar toda vez que o banco de dados é atualizado.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().Property(object => object.property).HasPrecision(12, 10);
```

*OBS: Todos os meus métodos que preciso inserir campos nessa condição também não são gravados com as 4 casas decimais, mas sim com apenas 2.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemente um `ModelBinder` como este:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        object result = null;

        string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        string attemptedValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName).AttemptedValue;

        string wantedSeperator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        string alternateSeperator = (wantedSeperator == "," ? "." : ",");

        if (attemptedValue.IndexOf(wantedSeperator) == -1
            && attemptedValue.IndexOf(alternateSeperator) != -1)
        {
            attemptedValue = attemptedValue.Replace(alternateSeperator, wantedSeperator);
        }

        try
        {
            // Faça um Debug desta lista. 
            // Se precisar, amplie a lógica dela para aceitar 4 casas.
            result = decimal.Parse(attemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, e);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Não esqueça de registrar o `ModelBinder` no `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();

        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Esse 'DecimalModelBinder' eu implementaria aonde? Pois se eu tiver que implementar na minha classe context, será apagado a cada atualização das classes (via DbFirst)...

Comment: Não possui alguma forma de eu criar um 'OnModelCreating' auxiliar e só **complementar** esse método com algumas linhas de código adicionando ao 'OnModelCreating' da classe contexto?

Comment: @AntônioFilho Eu uso um *namespace* do tipo: `MeuProjeto.Infrastructure.ModelBinders`. Aí não corre este risco de ser apagado. Fica a seu critério. Observe que um *model binder* não tem necessidade de acompanhar o *Code First* simplesmente porque é parte da aplicação, e não do banco, esta conversão.

Comment: Mesmo que esta resposta tenha sido aceite eu nao percebo como é que ela ajuda o AP. O AP menciona claramente que o valor é atribuido corretamente á propriedade antes de gravar na base de dados. Logo o problema nao pode estar relacionado aos *bindings*

Comment: Reparei agora que já tem 3 anos e por isso o meu voto já nem faz sentido. Peco desculpa

Answer (score 0):

> Quando eu insiro o comando abaixo na minha classe de contexto que é
>   gerada automaticamente, funciona normalmente, porém tenho que alterar
>   toda vez que o banco de dados é atualizado.

Você não deve modificar o código do seu contexto uma vez que ele é gerado automaticamente. 
Caso necessite de fazer alterações ao seu contexto faça num ficheiro separado. 
Repare que o contexto é gerado com a keyword `partial`. 
Isto permite-lhe implementar a lógica num ficheiro diferente que nunca é 
modificado pelo gerador automático de código.

```
partial public OMeuContexto{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().Property(o => o.property).HasPrecision(12, 10);
    }
}
```

Mais uma vez chamo a atenção. **Faca isto noutro ficheiro que não seja gerado automaticamente**